# Following documentation I cannot create an instance of Vue.js 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

## The code

https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-ttt?file=src/main.js

## The Problem

I'm trying to build a simple tic-tac-toe app in StackBlitz. This is my main.js file:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import TicTacToe from "./components/TicTacToe";
import Cell from "./components/Cell";

Vue.component("tic-tac-toe", TicTacToe);  // error: "cannot read property 'component' of undefined"
```

Also note my `package.json` file has vue as a dependency:

```
"dependencies": {
  "vue": "^3.0.0"
},
```

So the error means Vue needs to be defined, ok so I refer to [the 3x documentation](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/instance.html#creating-an-application-instance):

```
const app = Vue.createApp({ /* options */ })
```

But I get `Cannot read property 'createApp' of undefined`

---

So then I try to define an instance:

```
const Vue = new Vue({});
```

I get `Cannot access 'Vue' before initialization`

---

So, based on a google search of that error, I try:

```
Vue = new Vue({})
```

And I get `vue_1.default is not a constructor`.

## *So what am I doing wrong?*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you work with bundler like vue-cli, webpack or vite ..., you should import `createApp` to create new instance and use it for `app.use` or `app.component` ... :

```
 import { createApp } from "vue";
 const app = createApp({ /* options */ })
```

Using CDN like :

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
```

the Vue instance is available globally so you could use it as follows :

```
const app = Vue.createApp({ /* options */ })
```

Answer (score 5):

You are getting this error because Vue3 is using named export instead of a default export. You can read more about it [here](https://medium.com/@etherealm/named-export-vs-default-export-in-es6-affb483a0910).

You can fix this error by simply importing all the named exports onto an object called `Vue`:

```
import * as Vue from 'vue';
```

Comment: This is not a good idea if you're intending to use tree-shaking, as it will load the entire Vue object instead of just what you need. [Documentation](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/migration/global-api-treeshaking.html#internal-helpers)