# Vue CLI: Why does createApp work but Vue.createApp doesn't?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-cli-4

I'm confused about the difference between the CLI version of Vue.js and the normal version where you use a Vue istance.

On the initial build, the App.js file looks something like this:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { App } from './App.vue'

createApp(App).mount('#app')
```

and the app works fine.

But if I try to change it slightly and use:

```
import { Vue } from 'vue'
import { App } from './App.vue'

Vue.createApp(App).mount('#app')
```

all I get is a blank page.

I've been wanting to add a prototype to the Vue instance to access a global variable, but I don't see how if you can't use the Vue class normally.

What's the difference in functionality on the vue-cli when using `Vue.createApp` and `createApp`?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim I see that my app does work when using `createApp` vs `Vue.createApp`, but I don't understand *why* it works.

Comment: the first syntax is the correct one because there's no `import { Vue } from 'vue'` in vue 3, and `Vue.createApp` is valid only when using vue 3 via CDN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using the vue cli, the first syntax is correct because there's no `Vue` object imported from `vue`, for more explanation check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64418114/8172857). To add a global variable try to use `app.config.globalProperties.$globalVar` :

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { App } from './App.vue'

let app=createApp(App)
app.config.globalProperties.$globalVar=555;
app.mount('#app')
```